# How can I update a cv::namedWindow without using keys or that it closed meanwhile

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv in C++ and I have a question.

I want to show a `cv::Mat` image, which is quite easily possible with `cv::imshow` and `cv::namedWindow`. But I want to be able to see it and be able to update the `cv::Mat` meanwhile.

In fact I want to run my code, which creates the image, very often (automatically) and I want to see the updated version of the image in a window. This window is shown on a projector and there should be an up to date image visible on every moment.
And when the code is finished, I want to be able to see the last image until I close that window.

A simplified version of my code:

```
for (int i=1; i < 1000; ++i){
cv::Mat output_projector = cv::Mat::zeros(480, 848, CV_8UC3);
//..
//change the output_projector
//..
cv::namedWindow("Send to projector", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE|CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::imshow("Send to projector", output_projector);
cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just do like you did, but try increasing a little bit the time in the waitKey parameter. E.g. a standard movie is 25 fps, that is 4ms so try waitKey(4), or bigger values if this is too fast.

In order to see your image at the end, you should initialize it (and the window, by the way) before the loop, and call `waitKey(0)` eventually.

```
cv::Mat output_projector = cv::Mat::zeros(480, 848, CV_8UC3);
cv::namedWindow("Send to projector", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE|CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);

for (int i=1; i < 1000; ++i){
//..
//change the output_projector
//..
cv::imshow("Send to projector", output_projector);
cv::waitKey(10);
}
cv::imshow("Send to projector", output_projector);
cv::waitKey(0);
```